# when trying to dockerize spring boot application with mysql I get unable to start Tomcat while it works perfectly on localhost

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, tomcat

The mvn build is done successfully, the project works perfectly also on localhost, but once I try to dockerize the app by running the container and linking it to mysql container I get the errors below.
I'm going to walk you through all the steps I did :
*These are the steps I followed to dockerize the spring boot app with mysql :*

```
1/ docker pull mysql:5.7
2/docker run -it --name mysqldb  -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test -p 3308:3308 mysql:5.7
3/docker exec -it mysqldb bash
    4/ I created the database
    5/docker exec -i mysqldb mysql -uroot -ptest quizgame <quizgame.sql
    6/mvnw.cmd clean install -DskipTests
    7/docker build -f Dockerfile -t gamezquizapp .
    8/docker run -t --link mysqldb -p 8099:8099 gamezquizapp
```

Once I run the last command I get this trace of error of unable to start tomcat here is the top part of it as it is really too long, I tried to post here all the causes:

```
13:58:03.743 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301)
        at tn.esprit.quizgameapp.QuizGameAppApplication.main(QuizGameAppApplication.java:18)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:142)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:478)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:211)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:182)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160)
        ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setContentNegotationStrategy' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0;

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'openEntityManagerInViewInterceptorConfigurer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration.class]:

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'openEntityManagerInViewInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; 


Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration

Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration


Caused by: org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.valueextraction.ValueExtractorManager
```

Application.properties file:

```
server.port=8099
 ### DATABASE ###
debug=true
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3308/quizgame?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=test
 ### JPA / HIBERNATE ###
 spring.jpa.show-sql=true
 spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
 spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true
bezkoder.app.jwtSecret= *****
bezkoder.app.jwtExpirationMs= ****
spring.mail.host=****
spring.mail.port=***
spring.mail.username=****
spring.mail.password=****
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.writetimeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
 closeMethod="close"/>
  # Max file size.
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=20MB
# Max Request Size
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=20MB
```

my Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8099
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","target/QuizGameApp-1.0.jar" ]
```

.env file :

```
MYSQLDB_USER=root
MYSQLDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=test
MYSQLDB_DATABASE=quizgame
MYSQLDB_LOCAL_PORT=3308
MYSQLDB_DOCKER_PORT=3308
SPRING_LOCAL_PORT=8099
SPRING_DOCKER_PORT=8099
```

What am I doing wrong ?